# How to create a 3D map for iphone/ipad

Tags: iphone, ipad, opengl-es, 3d

is there any way i can create and render a 3d map on iphone/ipad?? I was searching and found 1 application which already do this http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rZtveCkW9Dc&feature=player_embedded

this company named [news scape technology](http://newscape-technology.com/demos.htm) is already doing this. I don't want to draw a complete city map just i want to know how they are doing it?? and how i can do this??

Should i draw map in blender or some tool and then use any graphic engine to render it or this is completely different thing??

what will be the best graphic engine opensource you will suggest to achieve this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rendering the map is absolutely not basic stuff. Nobody knows how those guys were doing that except themselves. I suggest you this 3d engines: [oolongengine](http://code.google.com/p/oolongengine/), [Ogre3D iPhone](http://ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/Ogre+iPhone&structure=Development)

Answer (score 0):

There are some 3D map SDKs by now, which makes 3D map as simple as 2D mapping: [Nutiteq Maps SDK](http://www.nutiteq.com), [G3M](http://www.glob3mobile.com) and possibly others, some are free and opens source, others (better supported and polished ones) are commercial ones. Disclaimer: I'm from Nutiteq